Overriding Amplify environment variable doesn't seem to work correctly
I have a React project that works perfectly fine until I deploy it to Amplify. I have two environments in Amplify -- staging and production. My environment variables work on staging, but not one specific variable which pertains to a 3rd party service.
Here are the variables:
staging:

production:

When I redeploy it all, staging works correctly. However, on production, it seems to keep referring to the staging variable:

Which results in an error:
Error: {"code":43,"StatusCode":401,"message":"WS failed with code 43 and reason - JWTAuth error: signature is not valid. Make sure the token is created using the secret for API key \"x62jnhxxxxxx\"","isWSFailure":false}

I've tried to change around the environments and keys to no avail. Am I doing anything wrong here?
